# Submitted form returns 'Resource id #12' as result

Tags: php, html, mysql

After submitting a form in PHP the database field for one field has "Resource id #12" as its content.  What is this supposed to mean and how do I find the issue?

```
$userid = $_POST['userid']; 
$paid = $_POST['paid']; 
$amountpaid = $_POST['amountpaid']; 
$method = $_POST['method']; 
$checknum = $_POST['checknum']; 
$invoicenum = $_POST['invoicenum'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO auction_payments (id,purchaser_id, 
invoicenum, amountpaid, method, checknum,on_date) VALUES('','$userid','$invoicenum','$amountpaid',
'$method','$checknum',NOW())") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What abou some code ?

Comment: Please post the sql statement for insert or update.

Comment: This isnt a human run search engine, ask specific queries arising out of work that you have done

Comment: I posted some code below sorry about that

Comment: Well despite almost loosing my account y'all disliked a beginner's question, I fixed it myself.  Thanks... for nothing.  Thats the only fault of this site is the people that kick us beginners off.

Comment: I have added your code to the question, btw. never use mysql_ functions any more, it´s deprecated...and i don't know if it was just in comment, but first you need to set variables with their values and then query them with function

Comment: @jessepfieffer A question gets downvotes if it is unclear or misses critical information. It is therefore unlikely to be useful to others, and experts are unlikely to be able to give a good answer. This way good questions bubble to the top, while 'bad' question float to the bottom. You can edit your own question with the edit link under your question (currently an edit is pending) and you are encouraged to do so if people request specific information via the comments.

Answer (score 2):

When you echo or print the result from `mysql_query` it will return the `Resource id #12`.
After the `INSERT` return the number affected rows [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) and test if the result is `larger than 0`. I would recommend using `mysqli` as `mysql` is depreciated.